# How to Refresh combobox in Visual Basic

Tags: combobox, vb6

When a button is clicked, it populates a combo box with all the databases you have created. Another button creates a new database. How do I refresh my combobox to add the newly added database?

Here's how I populate my combo box at the start:

```
rs.Open "show databases", conn
While Not rs.EOF
    If rs!Database <> "information_schema" Then
        Combo1.AddItem rs!Database
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
cmdOK.Enabled = False
cmdCancel.Enabled = False
frmLogin.Height = 3300

rs.Close
```

Comment: If it works instead of saying thanks .. Accept the answer

Comment: Add **DoEvents** to the next line after adding item to combo box.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have the database name to hand, it is a simple matter of:

```
Combo1.AddItem "<new database name>"
```

Otherwise, you should refresh the database list from source:

```
Sub RefreshDatabaseList(ByRef conn As Connection)

    Dim rs As Recordset

    ' Remove all previous entries.
    Combo1.Clear

    ' Rebuild the list.
    rs.Open "show databases", conn
    While Not rs.EOF
        If rs!Database <> "information_schema" Then
            Combo1.AddItem rs!Database
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refresh the comboboz

```
Combo1.Refresh()
```